# datatables set row color when certain condition is met

Tags: css, datatables

Each row of the table has an attribute called "id".

I want to have a red background for the row whose "id" is 8.

```js
var selectedId = 8;

table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {               
    if (this.data().id == selectedId) {
        $(table.row(rowIdx).node()).css('background-color', 'red'); // <-  does not work                  
        $(table.row(rowIdx).node()).addClass("redBackgroundClass"); // <-does not work
    }       
});
```

How can I dynamically add a red background to rows based on their id value?

**Please note**

In fact, i've reduced the above code to:

```
var node =$(table.row(0).node());
console.log(node); // <-- ok, console prints "<tr>"
node.css("background-color","red"); // <- does not work
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to set up a css class that includes the background color being red, then, after the dataTable has been loaded, assign that class to the rows who have an id of 8. You can do this with the `rowCallback` option in the DataTables initialization:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        //Other setup/config options go here
        rowCallback: function(row, data){
            if(data["id"] == 8){ //I'm assuming you're using object JSON/ajax, if not,
                                 //you'll have to find where in the data[] object the id is
                $(row).addClass("redBackgroundClass");
                //Or alternatively:
                //$(row).css("background-color","red"); if you don't want to make a css class
        }
    });
} );
```

With this code block, as long as you have a css class named "redBackgroundClass" with the appropriate background attribute, all rows with an id of 8 will have a red background.

**Edit:** As per @Carl's comment, you don't actually have to have a separate css class, you can just set the row's css background color if you want. I've included both in the code.

**Edit 2:** If you cannot access/modify the DataTables initialization for some reason, here is an alternative way to do it:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable(); //You don't have this line, but just note the name
                                       //'table' is the name of the DataTable object

var row = table
    .row('8') //This assumes that the official DT row index is named "8", if instead you
    .node();  //want the actual 8th row, just remove the ' marks and use row(8)

$(row).css("background-color","red");
```

**Edit 3:** You've correctly pointed out that this code is equivalent to your example, but note that there is a difference in that your example has an if statement before it. I got that example on the DataTables documentation, so the syntax of that is correct. I think that your problem must be either that if statement never evaluates to true or you are mistaken about where in the `data()` id is located. Try stepping through and seeing if you can confirm that those values are what you expect.

Comment: You don't have to use a CSS class or return anything in the function. You can just write `$(row).css("background-color","red")` in the if statement

Comment: @Carl That's true, I tend to use the classes more so that if I want to add other features down the line I can more easily, but if all he wants is the background that's probably simpler. I'll make a note in the answer.

Comment: thanks Chris, i cannot modify the code where the datatable is created, it is just handed over to me. Is there another alternative? thanks

Comment: @PrefijoSustantivo how is the datatable handed to you that you can't access the initialization?

Comment: there is a separate js file with a "createDataTable" function. It returns the id of it.
 I just get the datatable after it has been built with 

var table = $("#"+idTable).DataTable();

Comment: @PrefijoSustantivo If you make a `var table = &("#" + idTable).DataTable()` call, you are making a new DataTable anyway. You'll be overriding whatever settings were in the createDataTable  function anyways, so why not just add the `rowCallback` option to your new call? (Or just put all initialization options in one place)

Comment: when i pass the rowcallback parameter i get:

"  Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3 "

Comment: the suggested solution in "edit 2" is equivalent to the first "does not work" line i have in my code.

Comment: @PrefijoSustantivo If you really can't modify the initalization, then I think the only remaining problem with your "does not work" example is that `this.data().id` is never `==` to `selectedId` (8). I don't want to drag out an extended discussion in comments and I can't use chat right now, but I'd recommend taking a look at that if statement (mabye step through the code and see what those values are) or trying to change the initialization. I got that example code from [the dataTables docs](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector), so the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: i reduced the code so it has no "if" statement, it simply goes to the first row and calls jquery css, still not working. thanks anyway

Comment: @PrefijoSustantivo Try taking it out of the loop then. You shouldn't need to loop through all rows anyway, you can just directly access rows with an ID of 8.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. i had to iterate over the td's inside the tr and set their styles

```
var node = $(table.row(8).node());
node.find('td').each (function(index, value) {
    $(value).css("background-color","#AA0000");
    //$(value).addClass("redBGClass");  // this also works
});
```